# What is the result of wrapping a primitive value with Object?

Tags: javascript, object

So i was checking on my friend's assignment and I saw my friend used .map() to his array and it looked like this

```
let numbers = ['1','2','3','4','5']
numbers = numbers.map(Number)

// [1,2,3,4,5]
```

and all elements data type inside the array became number.
Then I tried to map the result with .map(Object) then it looked like this

```
[[Number: 1], [Number: 2], [Number: 3], [Number: 4], [Number: 5]]
```

When I print the typeof of the element, it shows that it is an object. But it was treated like numbers; I can use comparison operators on them, and it can be calculated like it was number alright.

```
[Number: 5] > [Number: 4] // true
[Number: 5] + [Number: 4] // 9
```

So what is this?

```
[Number: 1]
```

Comment: `numbers = numbers.map(Object)` return array of String

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's almost never something you need to deal with yourself. This is what the interpreter will do internally when you try to access a property of a primitive, eg:

```
const foo = 55;
foo.toFixed();
```

Primitives are not objects; primitive numbers *alone* do not have a `toFixed` property. When the interpreter sees that you're trying to access such a property on a primitive, it will turn the primitive into an object first - that is, something that has an internal prototype of `Number.prototype` (and `Number.prototype` is what has the `toFixed` method on it, which is why `foo.toFixed` can work).

By explicitly turning a primitive into an object, you'll see that its `typeof` is `object`, and if its properties are ever accessed later, it won't be automatically wrapped in an object by the interpreter (because it's already an object).

```js
const num = 55;
const objNum = Object(num);
console.log(typeof objNum);
console.log(
  Object.getPrototypeOf(objNum) === Number.prototype
);
```

When you try to use an operator like `>` or `+` on an object, the object will be (attempted to be) converted to its primitive value first, so that comparison, addition, concatenation, etc can occur.